# ERROR 42883: operator does not exist: text / text

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

When running the following query:

```
select data from example
where (data -> 'properties' ->> 'outageCount') / (data -> 'properties' ->> 'trackedCount') > 0.01
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 42883: operator does not exist: text / text
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Both `outageCount` and `trackedCount` are stored as integers in the JSONB.

I tried casting using `as float` but it gave following error:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
```

Comment: `->>` returns the value as a `text` value. So you need to cast that value to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the field is a JSON number, it will be returned as `text` (see [json and jsonb operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)):

```
db=# select pg_typeof(('{"foo":3}'::jsonb)->>'foo');
 pg_typeof
-----------
 text
(1 row)
```

You need to cast it by appending `::float` to the expression:

```
db=# select pg_typeof((('{"foo":3}'::jsonb)->>'foo')::float);
    pg_typeof
------------------
 double precision
(1 row)
```

In your case:

```sql
select data from example
where (data -> 'properties' ->> 'outageCount')::float / (data -> 'properties' ->> 'trackedCount')::float > 0.01
```